# jQuery Fancybox is not working for the first ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm using jQuery fancybox to show and hide loading animation on ajax requests.

```
$(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
      $.fancybox.showLoading();
    },
    complete: function(){
      $.fancybox.hideLoading();
    }
  });
});
```

It does not work for the first ajax request. But it works for subsequent requests.
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the proper global ajax events.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $.fancybox.showLoading();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
});
```